# How to update records using named scopes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use this bit of code to search for records using the the like query. Is it possible to create another scope which can update a record.

```
 scope :search, lambda{|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use rails' `update_all` method. See here for a description: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

EDIT: It's part of the Relation class, so you may call this on scopes (It doesn't say that explicit in the documentation)

EDIT2: It works very much like `destroy_all` which may also be called on scopes (Relation)

Comment: but looks like it doesnt respect default_scopes